# How to create a circle shape within UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, shapes

How can you create a circle image on a table cell?  For example:

[image]

This is our storyboard with the arrow pointing to where we are trying to draw a circle when we want to highlight the row:

[image]

---

*Update*:

Decided to do this using a custom font and associated [Swift library](https://github.com/Vaberer/Font-Awesome-Swift).  As Leo pointed out it is overkill to generate a circle when you can use an image (or font).  Was as easy as adding a new label and setting the font/icon:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ..
    if doHighlight {
        cell.statusLabel.setFAIcon(icon: .FACircle, iconSize: 6)
    }
    ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most performant way is to add an image that is round. Setting the `cornerRadius` will work, but it is a performance hog and it's an overkill for a simple colored circle.

Answer (score 1):

if height & width = 50

```
   View.clipsToBounds = true
   View.layer.cornerRadius= View.frame.size.width/2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a view that adds a `CAShapeLayer` with a circle:

```
@IBDesignable class CircleView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var fillColor:   UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)  { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor } }
    @IBInspectable public var strokeColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)  { didSet { shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor } }
    @IBInspectable public var lineWidth:   CGFloat = 0   { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    lazy private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let _shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        _shapeLayer.fillColor = self.fillColor.cgColor
        _shapeLayer.strokeColor = self.strokeColor.cgColor
        self.layer.insertSublayer(_shapeLayer, at: 0)
        return _shapeLayer
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = (min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) - lineWidth) / 2
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true).cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    }
}
```

Note, that is `@IBDesignable`, so you'll be able to use it in Interface Builder. Just create a separate target ("File" - "New" - "Target...") and choose "Cocoa Touch Framework" and give it an appropriate name (e.g. if your app is "Foo", you'd call this framework "FooKit"). Then add the above `UIView` subclass to that framework, and you can reference this class in IB (just add a `UIView` object and change its base class to `CircleView`):

[image: circle in IB]

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIView instance and set its `layer.cornerRadius` to half its width/height.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CircularImageView: UIImageView {
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let radius: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.clipsToBounds = true
} }
```

you can also make a circular image view which is subclass of UIImageView so you can set it directly to UIImageView...